# Objective-C private instance variables definition

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is there any difference in where we define private instance variables? As I understand there are two possibilties:

1) In header file

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
    @private
    NSString *fooString;
}
```

2) Second way is to define it in the implementation:

```
@implementation MyViewController
NSString *fooString;
```

What is the difference? Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In 2nd case `fooString` is not instance variable - it is global variable, so your two cases are completely different

Answer (score 4):

The first way defines a private instance variable. Each object of class MyViewController will have its own private fooString.

The second way defines a global variable. There will be only one instance of fooString and it will be visible to *any* source file with the following declaration:

```
extern NSString *fooString;
```

Answer (score 1):

The first one is a unique `fooString` per MyViewController that you create.

The second is a `fooString` that every MyViewController shares.